Trying to find a proof for Strong Axiom of Revealed Preference with general choice set
Note this is question is not about consumer demand with price and income data.
This is a question about general choice theory. For reference, see: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2550390
See Debreu's Definition 4 and condition C1.
$B$ is a menu set. $C(B)$ is a choice function with unique choice for each budget.
Definition: (direct revealed preference) we say $xPy$ if $y\in B$, $x\in C(B)$, and $x\neq y$.
Definition: (indirect revealed preference) $xP^*y$ if there exists a sequence $x_1,...,x_n$ and $B_1,...,B_n$ such that $x\in C(B)$, $x_1\in B$, $x_1\in C(B_1)$, $x_2\in B_1$... $x_n\in C(B_n)$ and $y\in B_n$.
$SARP$: $xP^*y$ implies not $yPx$.

To be proved: if $C$ satisfies $SARP$ then it is rationalizaed by a preference relation.

I tried to search the literature but I find no proof for this general version.

This is a special case of Theorem 1 of [Richter, Marcel K. "Revealed preference theory." Econometrica (1966): 635-645.]
